# Cannot import name QtTest running unittests for QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, mac, pyqt

I have the following imports in my unittest code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtTest
```

When I run my unit test from the command line I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name QtTest
```

QtCore and QtGui appear to load just fine.  Can anyone help me figure out why QtTest is different?

I'm running on a Mac OS X 10.10.5.  QGIS 2.8.3.  Python 2.7.10.  I believe or at least hope is the Python bundled with QGIS.  PyQt 4.11.3.

Comment: Just for info, I just tried the same operation on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits with QGIS 2.12.2 and it does not fail ( in QGIS Python console like directly from command line) So, it seems related to your Mac installation or configuration. Normally, you should find a `QtTest.so` file somewhere. Do you have it?

Comment: Thanks.  I did in fact find a QtTest.so.  It is installed with the pyqt installed by homebrew, but not in my QGIS install of pyqt.  I am trying to update my PYTHONPATH to point to the brew installed version of pyqt.